# Как тестировать запросы к API

Tags: javascript, test-driven-development, mocha, sinonjs

Здравствуйте. Стараюсь писать тесты к модулям. У меня есть модуль, который имеет примерно такую структуру:

```
class Article {
    static setNominate (pagename, nominateTemplate, callback) {
        Api.getText(
            pagename,
            text => {
                Api.setText(
                    pagename,
                    `${nominateTemplate}\n${text}`,
                    param => {
                        callback(param)
                    }
                )
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Модуль Api делает только ajax-запросы к серверу, примерно выглядящие так:

```
class Api {
    static getText (pagename, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url:  '/w/api.php',
            data: {
                action: 'parse',
                page:   pagename,
            },
            success: text => {
                callback(text)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

То есть запрос, а в колбэке ещё запрос. Давать управление управляющему модулю мне не очень приятно, так как это бездарно увеличит код и не даст абстракции. Поэтому, нужен запрос в запросе.

В тестах использую мочу, моча-дум и синон (где умею только $.ajax.calledWithMatch).

```
var assert = require('assert')
var sinon  = require('sinon')
var jsdom  = require('mocha-jsdom')
```

Comment: вы ведь пишите юнит тест?

Comment: Да, конечно. Сейчас пришло в голову, что мне наверное, поможет колбэк функция done из мочи, которая описана тут https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code

Comment: мокка, из мокки - а не то, что вы написали. если вы пишите юнит тест, то стоит использовать stub и/или mock.